Dynamic signatures issues in oracle apps r12.2 RTF
Dynamic signatures are created for each PO. When executed individually, each PO displays a different signature as expected. However, when I run a range of POs (e.g., 1 to 10), only the first signature is displayed for all. Can someone assist with this issue?
I have refreshed the variable in the PL/SQL, but the issue persists.
